# CRON expression to accomodate DST changes

Tags: cron, timezone, dst

We have 2 separate schedules, one for EST and one for EDT. One option is to manually adjust the schedule every few months with the exact start and end date. However, wondering if there is an option to automate and make it generic.

The expression would read: Run at 6 PM daily starting Second Sunday of March until the day before First Sunday of November.

Any help would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: If your system is set to the correct timezone, this will just work automatically.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But in this case, it is a cloud hosted system and that works on UTC timezone. Hence the need to accommodate for DST when it changes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.